# How do i loop over a list in R using $ operator and name of the list element?

Tags: r, list, loops, printing, names

For example, i have a simple list

```
sample <- list(Name="John",Age=32,Gender="M")
```

I can loop over this list and perform some function on its element:

```
for(i in names(sample)) {
   print(sample[[i]])
}

[1] "John"
[1] 32
[1] "M"
```

Is there a way to get the same result with something like the following instead:

```
for(i in names(sample)) {
   print(sample$i)
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work and will print the following to console

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but I recommend taking a look at the `*apply` family, specifically `lapply` and `mapply`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `$` operator?

Comment: @Hunaidkhan 'print(i)' would print the name of the element and not the element itself.  To answer Ronak and Maurits, I guess i am wondering if R is able to interpret 'sample[[i]]' to be 'sample[["Name"]]' correctly why does it not interpret 'sample$i' to 'sample$"Name"'